# connection string error for connecting withe remote system having LAN connection

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

```
connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.1,1433; Initial Catalog=challan; Integrated Security=false; User Id=sa2, Password=*****"
providerName="system.data.sqlclient"
```

The above connection string shows an error

> Login failed for user 'sa2, Password=abc'

Settings:

- Shared Memory=Disabled
- Named pipes=Enabled
- TCP/IP=Enabled
- VIA=Disabled

The connection between the two laptops are made using LAN cable, both the SQL Server get connected in both the systems.

In Microsoft SQL Server, the remote connection gets connected to the host using userid=sa2 and password=*****, but the connection string is showing an error.

Comment: `192.168.0.1/1433` ???

Comment: IP address of the remote system, from which connection is to be taken.

Comment: I think that @Sachu pointed you to use slash instead of a comma.

Comment: @Littlefoot yes but i thought he is using oracle.in sql connection no need to mention the port.

Comment: @pradeep either try `192.168.0.1/1433` or `192.168.0.1`